# Are shared library ABI compatible as long as their versions are the same?

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library

Suppose I have a program compiled that's linked against libc.so.6 on one system (e.g., Ubuntu x64). If I take this binary to another system that has the same libc version 6 (e.g., Fedora x64), it seems to run fine.

My question is, is it more-or-less a contract that the ABI is stable as long as the so versions are identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not necessary that shared libraries be ABI compatible cross-distro. I think it's a reasonable expectation, but ABI breaks happen and you can't rely on ABI compatibility blindly.

An example would be `libstdc++`. On Ubuntu 16.04 (with GCC 5) and CentOS 7 (with GCC 4.8), the respective `so`s fall on opposite sides of [an ABI break](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html). Software compiled on Ubuntu 16.04 with C++ but without `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` set would not run on CentOS 7. They're both still `libstc++.so.6`. ABI breaks may also happen with bug-fix patches applied by distro maintainers, who would not usually bump the `so` major version numbers for bug fixes.

Comment: Out of interest, would this depend on the compiler _alone_ or on the combination of compiler and Linux distribution?  I.e., could this still be a problem within a _single_ Linux distribution?

Comment: @Kusalananda well, the bug-fix breaking ABI would be within the same release of the same distro, but I don't have any good examples of that handy.

Comment: @muru Thank you. Just out of curiosity, is there a similar ABI rule for libc? I tried googling this but my google-fu is weak :(

Comment: @wbkang there's the [musl vs glibc](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html) problem.